# how to call a overridden method from subclass object in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Is there a way to call `test()` in class a from class *b* object created in class *c* ?

```
class a {
 void test(){
   System.out.println("in a");
  }
}

 class b extends a {
   void test(){
     System.out.println("in b");
   }
}

public class c{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   b refb = new b();
   refb.test();
  }
}
```

Comment: the super keyword, but then that would be from within b.

Comment: you can't do that in java.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that only within the `test()` method of class `b` like following.

```
class b extends a {
   void test(){
     super.test();
     System.out.println("in b");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to change class b code, is there a way to call from b's object refb in class c

Comment: @Jayadeep; That's a violation of encapsulation. You can't do that. May be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan that won't be the case in languages like C++ or C# where you can leave the method as non-`virtual`. See my answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : I'm not familiar with C# or C++. But, in java, we can't do it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all non `static private` methods are `virtual` by default. So, **there's no way** to invoke `a#test` from `b` instance unless you modify `b#test`. The only way to do it (by your current design) is using an instance of `a`:

```
public class c{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b refb = new b();
        // code to call test() in class a
        //this is the only way you have in Java
        a refA = new a();
        a.test();
    }
}
```